# To check if two strings match with alphabets, digits and special characters

Tags: java, python, string, compare, character

How would you write a function that takes in two strings, and returns true if they match (Without the use of regular expressions).

Constraints are as follows:

- String 1 (the text to match to) will have alphabets and digits.
- String 2, the pattern, will be alphabets, digits, `.` and `*`, where `.` means either alphabet or digit will be considered as a match and `*` means the previous character is repeat 0 or more times.

For example:

```
Text: Facebook
Pattern: F.cebo*k
returns True
```

Comment: Try looking up Regular Expressions. This isn't exactly what Stack Overflow is for...

Comment: I think your example should return false ....

Comment: Agree with @JoranBeasley - looks like your example would match `stackoverfllw` (if * means the previous character is repeated)

Comment: @user1530318  still should return false. ... as `b*ok` would not match `book`

Comment: Your current one would match `facebbok`

Answer (score 2):

what you just described is refered to as a regular expression (although `.` means "anything" in regular expression).... there is already a library for this

also your example is wrong .. as `"flow"` would not match `"fl*w"` , however it would match `"fl.w"`

```
import re
string2=string2.replace(".","[0-9a-zA-Z]")
print re.match(string2,string1)
```

here is a statemachine implementation that should work for all cases except when it starts with *

```
def matcher(pat,txt):
    last = None
    try:
        for ltr in txt:
            if ltr == pat[0]:
                pat = pat[1:] #consume
            elif pat[0] == "*" and ltr == last:
                 #dont consume
                continue # dont change last
            elif pat[0] == "*" and ltr == pat[1]:
                pat = pat[2:] #consume 2 (* + whatever)
            elif pat[0] =="*"  and last == ".":
                continue #dont consume and dont change last 
            elif pat[0] == ".":
                pat = pat[1:]#consume
            elif pat[1] == "*"  and ltr == pat[2]:
                pat = pat[3:] #consume 3 (x*X)
            else:
                return False
            last = ltr
    except IndexError:
        return False #there was a problem that made it break ... it also doesnt match
    if not pat or pat == "*":
        return True

    return False
print "Matching Pattern bo*k"
for word in "boak,bok,book,booooooook,boo,bk".split(","):
    print word ," ?=",matcher("bo*k",word)
```

which outputs

```
Matching Pattern bo*k
boak  ?= False
bok  ?= True
book  ?= True
booooooook  ?= True
boo  ?= False
bk  ?= True
```

Comment: @user1530318 Why wouldn't you use the RE library? This is what it was built for...

Comment: This was an interview question that I completely blanked out on, just curious how it would be done

Comment: if it was an interview question and had to do with python they wanted you to use built ins ... not reinvent a complicated algorithm ... however to see how it constructs a state machine see  http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/

Comment: what makes you think they wanted you to implement the algorithm? as opposed to using one that already exists (There are equivelents in pretty much every major language)

Comment: anyway I implemented a state machine ... that is some subset of regex

Answer (score 2):

Not particularly proud of this (@JoranBeasley's answer is the best), but this will work (seemingly) without regex:

```
def Matcher(pattern, text):
  comp = zip(pattern, text)
  for i, vals in enumerate(comp):
    if vals[0] != vals[1]:
      if vals[0] == '.' and vals[1].isalnum():
        continue
      elif vals[0] == '*' and vals[1] == comp[i-1][0]:
        continue
      else:
        return False
  return True

print 'F.cebo*k -> Facebook'
print Matcher('F.cebo*k', 'Facebook')

print 'St.c.koverflow -> Stackoverflow'
print Matcher('St.c.koverflow', 'Stackoverflow')

# And for nostalgia...
print 'St.ckoverfl*w -> Stackoverfllw'
print Matcher('St.ckoverfl*w', 'Stackoverfllw')
```

I'm sure it's riddled with errors (like if a string starts with a `*`), but my code usually is.

Comment: naw thats cool :)(+1) pretty decent state machine implementation ... that does (basically) what he asked for .... but I dont think the goal of the question was to implement the algorithm ... i think it was testing if he knew about regex's (but i think `bo*k` would not match `boook` as it should ...and also would not match `bk` so there is still some implementation details for the OP

Comment: I'll take a +1 from @JoranBeasley any day :) And I agree with your regex point - although I'm sure interviewers ask off-the-wall stuff often, seems like knowledge of what regex is would trump implementing a relatively simple algorithm.

Comment: @JoranBeasley And good points about the matching - back to the lab :)

Comment: I posted one also (inspired by you)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Very cool! That looks much better than mine. +1 back at you, and hopefully an accepted answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at Regular Expressions. They return true if they find something.

```
import re
if re.findall(regex, string):
  print "You found it!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expresions will help you [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)